# How to abort XCode Bot build?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, xcode-bots

I have a problem with Xcode bots. I'm able to compile, test and archive my project, but I would like to use external tool that checks if I did code review for last commits. I would like to be able to abort build if there is no code review. 
I tried to add `exit 1` or `exit 0` in `pre-build` script but it just ends given script not whole building process. So my question is how I can abort Xcode bot build (integration)?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue ?

Comment: kinda :P you can just remove project - build will fail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, it is possible. You can cancel an integration, which immediately aborts it. It's a very similar process to triggering an integration from the command line, which I [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30062418/909246), but you would first need to find out the `_id` of the integration by calling using the endpoint `/xcode/api/bots/BOT_ID/integrations` and the first integration should be the latest. Copy the `_id` and then call a POST on `/xcode/api/integrations/INTEGRATION_ID/cancel`, which will cancel the integration.

I use all these APIs in my tool [Buildasaur](https://github.com/czechboy0/Buildasaur), so check out the source code for more details.

Comment: Tool sounds promising :). I will dig into it in few days and possibly get back to you with some questions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to czechboy's answer, here is a solution for copy & paste friends. Use something like this as pre-integration script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# something returning an error code like:
${XCS_PRIMARY_REPO_DIR}/customPreIntegrationConfiguration.sh

# if script exits with error code 1:
if (( $? )); then
    echo "canceling integration ${XCS_INTEGRATION_ID}..."
    curl -kX POST "https://localhost:20343/api/integrations/${XCS_INTEGRATION_ID}/cancel"
fi
```

`$?` checks the exit code of the last command, in this case the script. If you are using a pipe somewhere, it can be necessary to use `set -o pipefail` to return 1 if only one pipe component returns 1.